# Arrays not incrementing properly when reading from a file in C

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_MAX 100

int main() {

    FILE *input, *output;
    char *token[100];
    char buf[100];
    int count = 0;
    input = fopen("/Users/home/Desktop/test.txt", "r");
    output = fopen("/Users/home/Desktop/test2.txt", "w");

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), input) != NULL) {
        token[count] = strtok(buf, "\n");
        ++count;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<count; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", token[i]);
    }

    printf("%d\n\n" ,count);
    return 0 ;

}
```

When I run this code I get the output like

line 3

line 3

line 3

rather than getting a result like

line 1

line 2

line 3

What an I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post your input.

Comment: `token[count] = strtok(buf, "\n");` does not copy the "string"-token.

Comment: what happens when the input contains more that 100 lines?

Comment: this line: #define ARRAY_MAX 100 seems to indicate that each array is to 100 entries, however all the array sizes are hardcoded to 100 rather than using the ARRAY_MAX.  Also, the values of a #define should always be surrounded by ( and )  to avoid errors when using the value as part of an expression

Answer (score 2):

`strtok()` is being run on the same `buf` each time, and so will return the same address each time. When the loop completes, the last-read value is in the buffer, so that's what prints.

You want to save *copies* of the lines:

```
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), input) != NULL) {
    token[count] = strdup( strtok(buf, "\n") );
    ++count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The assignment

```
token[count] = ...
```

merely copies the address of the buffer into the pointer. You then re-use the same buffer, and copy the same address into the next element of the array. What you need to do is allocate memory for each new line as it is read and copy the *contents* of the buffer into the newly allocated memory:

```
token[count] = malloc(strlen(buf) + 1); // +1 for trailing 0
strcpy(token[count], buf);
```